# function selector not found in hardhat node

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I am trying to call a smart contract, `getTokenDepositAmount(uint inputToken)`, from frontend (Reactjs) using ethers.js but I am getting this error in browser console:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getTokenDepositAmount(uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

and in hardhat node console, I am getting this:

```
eth_call
  Contract call:       UniswapClone#<unrecognized-selector>
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x9fe46736679d2d9a65f0992f2272de9f3c7fa6e0

  Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
      at UniswapClone.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/UniswapClone.sol:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at HardhatNode.runCall (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:639:20)
      at EthModule._callAction (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:354:9)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:188:20)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (/home/rishabh/Documents/projects/uniswap-clone/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:167:17)
```

Smart contract function:

```
function getTokenDepositAmount(uint inputToken) public view returns (uint) {
        uint256 ethReserve = address(this).balance; 
        return ((inputToken * tokenReserve) / ethReserve) + 1;
    }
```

I don't have revert statement here still I am getting this error. May anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

***Note: I am already on localhost:8545 and imported one of the account from hardhat node into metamaks***

### EDIT

Here's the code where I called the function:

```
async function fetchDepositTokenAmount() {
    console.log(contract);
    const depositAmount = await contract.getTokenDepositAmount(
      ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
    );
    console.log("deposit amount: ", depositAmount);
  }
```

Comment: hey, can you please show the code where you do the call?

Comment: @donoso.eth I have added the code where I have called it

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the correct contract on the correct chain?

Comment: did you deploy a contract to the address 0x9fe46736679d2d9a65f0992f2272de9f3c7fa6e0 or are you forking mainnet? the error suggests that the contract deployed to this contract misses the function you are calling

Answer (score 0):

have you try converting the amount en advance?

```
async function fetchDepositTokenAmount() {
    console.log(contract);
    let amount =  ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
    const depositAmount = await contract.getTokenDepositAmount(amount);
    console.log("deposit amount: ", depositAmount);
  }
```

Now it should work. Hope t helps